# Weirdly arising sound artifacts when panning (dual guitar tracks)

Tags: guitar, recording

I can't really share the audio file (because I removed those issues by softening the sound), but here's what I'm talking about:

I use a lexan pick, which sounds great, adds some highs (compared to tortex or Gator Grip (Dunlop in this case)), but also adds a click at the start of a transient (I mean chugs and riffs). So I record the left channel, listen to it with center panning and I slightly hear that click. I pan the recording to the left – click disappears! I pan it opposite click is there again. And vise versa. When only one track out of those two hard panned has that click, it sounds fine, but when both have the click, it produces an unpleasant sound (but as I said earlier, I fixed that).

So how can that be explained? I hear click with center panning, I don't hear it when it's panned hard left and I hear it again when it's panned hard right.

Comment: Have you performed a frequency analysis of the recording? Are there any weird artefacts that disappear after panning?

Comment: Sounds like your speakers are not identical. Like perhaps one is damaged or there are some reflective surfaces near one of them that is changing what you’re hearing from it. What happens if you conduct the same experiment with headphones?

Comment: @ToddWilcox I am doing it in the headphones.

Comment: @Pyromonk No, no other artifacts (no pops, no formant shifts (those sometimes did happen when overusing Flex, you sometimes get like a deep dive when shifting the left or right corners on adjacent regions, on one of which flex is disabled)), just the pick clicks.

Comment: I’d try different headphones or speakers to see if still happens. Also check your ears. Just flip the headphones around and see if it follows the flip or stays. You could have some hearing lose in one ear.